# Cron jobs not being called, getting email notification errors

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab, ssh

I've been having a hard time getting my cronjobs working for my new magento 1.9.2.3 install.  I added a mailto along with my cron call in crontab and i've been getting back error messages like this:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /usr/local/lib/php.ini on line 3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.31
Content-type: text/html



Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in /home/kegel4/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:344
Stack trace:
#0 /home/kegel4/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/kegel4/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/kegel4/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/kegel4/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/kegel4/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/kegel4/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Mo in /home/kegel4/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 344
```

Comment: UPDATE: added php.ini calling the PBO to lib folder and now I'm only getting this error...

PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /usr/local/lib/php.ini on line 3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.31
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(/abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/kegel4/public_html/shell/scheduler.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/abstract.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/kegel4/public_html/shell/scheduler.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /usr/local/lib/php.ini on line 3
```

Paste that file `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` here, so people can tell you how to fix that syntax error

Comment: I found this: ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);

Comment: Is this all the content of the file? If so, just delete that file (or rename it). Or, if you want to keep that config, change that line for max_execution_time = -1